# How to save state of chrome developers tools device metrics and emulate touch events?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I want to have device width metrics, user agent and touch events to be saved even after I  close the developer tools and close the browser. Can I set default settings for all Chrome windows and tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. In the user settings, you'll see a checkbox "Enable on DevTools startup".  Check that box and in addition to the values being saved, every time you open the developer tools your settings will be applied.

To turn on:

1. Open Chrome's developer tools (F12 on a PC)
2. Open settings. (Hit the gear icon in the lower right).
3. Set your device emulation, orientation, width height, geolocation
   overrides, etc.
4. Hit the "Enable on DevTools startup" checkbox at the top.
5. Close Settings

To turn it off, just uncheck the box.

Comment: Yep, now it's available, in the past i was trying my own chrome extension that does this using dev tools API.